# On Kähler submanifolds

Tags: kahler-manifolds

Given $m+1$ points $x_0,\ldots x_m$ on a Kähler manifold of complex dimension $>m$, is there always an $m$-dimensional Kähler submanifold containing $x_0,\ldots x_m$?

Perhaps some kind of geodesic closure?

Comment: No. Many Kähler manifolds do not contain any nontrivial complex submanifold. This is the case for instance of a general complex torus.

Comment: Do you insist on closed submanifolds, or do you allow nonclosed embedded submanifolds, or do you even perhaps allow immersed submanifolds? There is a connected immersed complex curve, I believe, through any finite number of points in any connected Kaehler manifold, related to finiteness of Kobayashi metric. I think @abx is thinking of closed complex submanifolds.

Comment: @BenMcKay: I don't know exactly what to expect, so anything constructive in the direction of my question is useful. Ideally, I'd like to have something where the Kähler potential is obtained simply by restriction of the  original Kähler potential. An immersed submanifold should be fine, closedness would not be essential.